# Azure DevOps view code via web restriction

Tags: azure-devops

Does anybody know if it is possible to prevent a user of Azure DevOps from being able to see code on the web interface and force to checkout locally in order to see it. I am looking this feature in Team Foundation Server 2015 as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know if it is possible to prevent a user of Azure DevOps from being able to see code on the web interface and force to checkout locally in order to see it.

To achieve this, we could set the access level of that specify user as **stakeholder**.

In this case, that user do not have permissions to see code on the web interface:

[image]

To checkout it locally, we could provide a `PAT`, which have permission access the repo to the user, so that that user could use git command line to checkout it:

```
git clone <repo>(https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample) <directory>
```

Besides, this method should also work for Team Foundation Server 2015.

**Update:**

> is it posible to just restrict view of code on the web for a user with
> a visual studio subscription, the porblem is that an stakeholder might
> be very limited...

The answer is yes. Go to the `Project Settings`-> `Repositories`-> Add a specify user and set the `Read` permission as `Deny`:

[image]

Then we could not acess the code on the web UI:

[image]

Comment: is it posible to just restrict view of code on the web for a user with a visual studio subscription, the porblem is that an stakeholder might be very limited...:-(

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez, The answer is yes, please check my updated answer for some more details.

Comment: So i assume this will only apply to repository via web and the developer will not be able to see the code via web can check in and check out locally, correct ?

Comment: @RobertoGonzalezr, The answer is yes, but when you check in and check out locally, you need use the PAT which have permission access the repo to the user. If the suer use the PAT create by himself, it still have no permission access the repo.

Comment: Thanks I will test, I assume this only applies to git repositories on azure devops, and for TCVC ? is it the same ?

Comment: I have tested both for git and tcvc and does not work, maybe I am going something wrong? Any other idea?

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez, it works fine on my side. So, you may need share how you did it, the more detailed the better, and what your mistake is